# Does Jack of All Trades count for having proficiency in Performance for practicing a profession?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, bard, proficiency

According to p. 187 of the PHB, you can use your Performance skill to maintain a wealthy lifestyle during downtime, if you have proficiency in it.

Does having the Jack of All Trades feature count?

For reference, the PHB states on p. 57 that

> [...] you can add half your proficiency bonus [...] to any ability check [...]

It states "add half your proficiency" rather than "are half proficient," however that may be because it applies to things that you cannot be proficient in, e.g. [initiative](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46797/33677).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, **Jack of All Trades** doesn't count as *having* proficiency. All it does is change how you calculate your bonuses when rolling for a skill, and the rule for practicing a profession during downtime don't care about that. This rule only cares whether you really have proficiency in a skill (PHB, p. 187, emphasis mine):

> If you **have proficiency** in the Performance skill and put your performance skill to use during your downtime, you earn enough to support a wealthy lifestyle instead.

So no, Jack of All Trades won't let you be a rock star. (On the other hand, what is a bard doing with her life if she *doesn't* have proficiency in Performance so she can be a rock star?!)

Answer (score 11):

Jack of All Trades does not give you proficiency in any skill that you are not proficient in. It may grant you a bonus to ability checks that are otherwise made without proficiency, but it does not make you proficient. You are only proficient in a skill if you have a game feature which states that you are proficient.