# Does Passive Initiative exist (can it be used instead of rolling for Initiative)?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, initiative

Initiative is an ability check.

From what I understand, a DM may ask his players to use Passive scores for ability checks and/or use them for his NPCs (ex: Passive Perception).

Is Passive Initiative something that can be used by a DM, by RAW ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It's called the "Initiative Score"

Yes, there are passive initiative checks. See DMG, page 270, "Initiative Variants":

> **Initiative Score**
>   With this optional rule, creature don't roll initiative
>   at the start of combat. Instead, each creature has an
>   initiative score, which is a passive Dexterity check:
>   10 + Dexterity modifier.

[Jack of all trades and Remarkable athlete will add one-half proficiency to this passive ability score.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46799/22566)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose You don't usually add your proficiency bonus to Initiative rolls anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't Jack of All Trades or Remarkable Athlete add a bonus to that passive check?  (Fighter, Champion)  *Starting at 7th level, you can add half your proficiency bonus (round up) to any Strength, Dexterity, or Constitution check you make that doesn’t already use your proficiency bonus*

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it does https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46796/

Comment: OK, I added a link since that will improve the Fighter's and the Bard's passive score, but  most others probably not.

Comment: I assume Swashbuckler would have charisma added here as well?

Comment: And of course, if you have advantage to Initiative checks, you'd add a +5 in there.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford, one of the 5e designers, recently recommended using Initiative Score for monsters but keeping rolling for players as another option. For some groups, this is the best of both worlds.

Comment: @DerekStucki Except, of course, if you as a DM tend to use many of the same monsters, they all go in a clump.

Comment: @Yakk, that is the default. The section on rolling initiative says to group similar monsters.