# Does an already controlled mount need to roll for Initiative?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, initiative, mounted-combat

The Player's Handbook has this to say about Controlling a Mount:

> The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. (...) A controlled mount can move and act even on he turn that you mount it.

If someone is already controlling a mount before a combat starts, **does the already controlled mount need to roll for Initiative ?**

If so, then I suppose the result would instantly get overridden by the mounter's initiative.

If not, then it would bring an interesting scenario if, during the combat, the mounter dismounts the mount -- perhaps, at that point, the mount would need to roll initiative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, it doesn't.

The rule you quoted is the only change to initiative that is specified. If you dismount, the mount can keep its current initiative value, which is the same as yours. Its turn would be either before or after the dismounted character's turn.
I would decide based on what actions either of them have already taken. For example, if the character has used their action, I would rule their turn is before the mount's turn.